# What does "can't get a beat on you" mean?

Tags: expressions

In family guy, season 12 episode 4 the handicapped cop gives grimace a ride a along. While driving the car he stares suspiciously at grimace and says "I can't get a beat on you".

What does that expression mean?

Comment: It's probably "I can't [get a bead](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+a+bead+on) on you"

Comment: It turns out "get a beat on" is also a legit saying, according to this post at Language  Log: "[And the Bead Goes On](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/myl/languagelog/archives/000308.html)"

Comment: @CopperKettle That just seems like a lot of apologizing for writers who don't know their idioms misquoting speakers.

Answer (score 2):

I would have to watch the episode in question to be 100% certain, but I'm *nearly* certain that he actually said "[get a bead on](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+a+bead+on)".

'Bead' and 'beat' will sound essentially identical in many North American accents.

The 'bead' in the phrase 'get a bead on' is referring to the bead on the end of a gun with bead [iron sights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_sights). Literally speaking, if you have a bead on someone, then your gun is aimed at them. Figuratively speaking, this means you know exactly where they are, or what they are doing. If you can't get a bead on someone, you either don't know where they are, or don't understand their actions or intent.